# "Permission denied to access property 'print' " in Firefox when printing PDF from DynamicReport. Changing 'pdfjs.disabled' not helped

Tags: jquery, firefox, pdf, printing, dynamic-reports

I am using Dynamic Report in Servlet to generate a PDF and out put it to jsp page using the code

```
report.toPdf(response.getOutputStream());
```

In Jquery I am loading the pdf in a new window as a popup

```
var newWindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=800,width=1000');
            if (window.focus) {
                newWindow.focus();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    newWindow.print();
                }, 2000);
            }
```

But this returns an error

> Error: Permission denied to access property "print"

Firefox version is 43.0 . I tried changing 'pdfjs.disabled' to 'true' in about:config, but that's not  helping: when that's set and tried to print, the window closes automatically right-away and the pdf gets auto-saved and console shows the error:

> "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:"

.

> Updated Question

I just realized the problem is not just with print, I tried retrieving the HTML contents from the page with.

```
setTimeout(function() {
                $(newwindow.document).ready(function() {
                    $(newwindow.document).find("body").on("load", alert($(newwindow.document).find("body").html()));
                });
            }, 2000);
```

The returned an error,

> Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

Now if I remove the setTimeout() function on both the above codes, first one will print a blank page, and second alerts blank. i.e, the contents are not getting loaded by then i guess.

Comment: Is the PDF showing as secured/restricted? (Adobe Reader `Document Properties >> Security` can be used to view security info).

Comment: There are no security restrictions for printing it and 'Security Method: No Security'. The only features "Not Allowed" are, 'Document Assembly' and 'Page Extraction'.